# Identifying old and new values on changed objects with NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to track changes to objects in a core data context, tracking the name of properties that have changed along with the old and new values.

I've registered for `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` to receive a notification when a save is about to occur, and can pull out the inserted/updated/deleted objects from the context... I can then see the changed values using .changedValues.

However, I am having difficulties retrieving the old values...

As an example, I have an object that tracks a position, and so one of the changes comes back with:

```
po [obj changedValues]
{
    originX = 260;
    originY = 180;
}
```

This gives me the new values for the properties that have changed on the object. To try and get the old values, I'm then using `changedValuesForCurrentEvent`, which according to the docs should return

> "a dictionary containing the keys and old values of persistent
>   properties that have changed since the last posting of
>   `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`"

However, when I try this, it is coming back empty...:

```
po [obj changedValuesForCurrentEvent]
{
}
```

How can I capture the old and new values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're mixing up your notifications. `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` gets called any time you change values on a managed object, even though you haven't saved changes yet. `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` gets called later on when you save. So the sequence is:

1. You change some attributes --> `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` is posted, and you can use `changedValuesForCurrentEvent` to see what changed.
2. Later, you save changes. `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` is posted. You can call `changedValuesForCurrentEvent`, but it's not helpful because it returns changes *since the last did-change notification*. There are no changes since the last did-change notification. If there were, you would have received another one. That method is documented to be useful on a did-change notification, not on a will-save notification.

If you want the old values *and* you want to get them when the will-save notification is posted, you have a couple of options:

- Listen for `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`. Cache information about changes in some collection object (probably `NSDictionary`). Then when `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` happens, look up those changes, process them, and clear the change cache. OR...
- When you get `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification`, create a second local managed object context. Since this is a **will** save notification, you can still fetch the old values. So, fetch each object that's getting saved and compare the before and after values to see what's different.

Comment: Thankyou very much for the good explanation, that definitely helps clarify things!

Comment: There is a simpler way: You can use `committedValues(forKeys:)` to get changes that are not yet saved. See my answer below.

Comment: No the simpler way is to use the correct notification

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is 4 years old, Eddie's answer was very helpful. I made a little change to his answer. All the credits goes to him.

```
object.setValuesForKeys(object.committedValues(forKeys: object.changedValues().map { $0.key }))
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is old, but there is a better way than the accepted answer. You can access the previous values via  [committedValues(forKeys:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506771-committedvalues) in combination with [changedValues()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506775-changedvalues). There is no need to handle `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` or to create another managed object context.

Here is some sample code that I use:

```
// For some reason, the Swift compiler chokes on the type of object.changedValues().keys.
// It should be of type [String], but it complains that it is of type `Dictionary<String, Any>.Keys`
// which is useless. Ah, the joys of Apple programming...
// Work around that like so:
var changedKeys = [String]()
for (key, _) in object.changedValues() {
    changedKeys.append(key)
}
let oldData = object.committedValues(forKeys: changedKeys)
```

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you should call ["`changedValuesForCurrentEvent`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/changedValuesForCurrentEvent) ***only*** when you receive [your "`NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification`" notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification).

And if "`changedValuesForCurrentEvent`" still returns a null dictionary or object, check to see if the notification had anything useful in it's "`userInfo`" dictionary itself.  It also may be that there has not been a `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`" posted, like you posted from the docs up there.