# Persist offline changes separately from original data in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, offline-mode

I'm in the middle of adding an "offline mode" feature to an app I'm currently working on. Basically the idea is that users should able to make changes to the data, for example, edit the description of an item, without being connected to the internet, and the changes should survive between app launches.

Each change would normally result in an API request when working online but situation is different in offline mode.

Right now this is implemented by storing all data coming from the API in a Core Data database that acts as a cache. Entities that can be edited by user in addition to normal attributes have the following ones:

- `locallyCreated` - whether the object was created offline
- `locallyDeleted` - object was deleted offline
- `locallyUpdated` - updated

This makes it possible to look for new/deleted/updated objects and send corresponding API requests when doing sync.

This worked well for creating and deleting objects, however, one disadvantage I found with this approach is when new data is retrieved from the API all local changes (i.e. attributes of objects marked as locally updated) are lost, which means that they have to be stored separately somehow.

What would be the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have your `locallyUpdated` key, the obvious answer is to modify your code that imports server changes, so that it doesn't overwrite changes to any object marked as changed. One way or another you need to avoid overwriting those changes, and you're already keeping a record of which objects *have* changes, so you already have the tools for a basic solution.

But you'll soon run into the complexity of syncing data. What if the local object has changes on one key, but the incoming data from the server has changes on a different key? You can't resolve that just by knowing that the local copy has changed somehow. Maybe you decide that the server always wins, or that the local copy always wins. Those are easy, if they make sense for your app. If you need to merge changes though, you have some work ahead of you. You would need to record not only a Boolean value indicating that changes were made, but also a list of which keys had changed. This can get complicated, but it's the nature of data syncing.

Comment: I was thinking about storing a dictionary with changed properties and their values but then I would need to somehow tweak all property accesses to look at updated values first and only then at actual `NSManagedObject` attributes. Honestly I'm a little bit lost right now, I kind of keep thinking that it's possible to do this with Core Data merge policies but I've never worked with them so I don't even know if that will work. I guess I'll have to experiment. Thank you!

Comment: Rather than changing your accessors, the strategy described here might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433838/identifying-old-and-new-values-on-changed-objects-with-nsmanagedobjectcontextwil/23435466#23435466

Comment: It's funny, I googled that answer yesterday :) It seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Do you know how to discard changes to specific properties inside a `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` handler? Simply setting them to the old values causes the same notification to fire again so there needs to be guard mechanism to avoid infinite recursion. I suspect there is a simpler way of doing this...

Comment: No, because that's not intended as a validation step. At that point the value has already changed, so discarding it really means making a new change that happens to go back to the previous value. If you need to validate values, that may need to go in accessor methods.